# json key iteration in DW mule

Tags: json, mule, dataweave

I have the following requirement need to interate the dynamic json key 
need to use this json key and iterate through it
This is my input

```
[  
  {  
    "eventType":"ORDER_SHIPPED",
    "entityId":"d0594c02-fb0e-47e1-a61e-1139dc185657",
    "userName":"educator@school.edu",
    "dateTime":"2010-11-11T07:00:00Z",
    "status":"SHIPPED",
    "additionalData":{  
      "quoteId":"d0594c02-fb0e-47e1-a61e-1139dc185657",
      "clientReferenceId":"Srites004",
      "modifiedDt":"2010-11-11T07:00:00Z",
      "packageId":"AIM_PACKAGE",
      "sbsOrderId":"TEST-TS-201809-79486",
      "orderReferenceId":"b0123c02-fb0e-47e1-a61e-1139dc185987",
      "shipDate_1":"2010-11-11T07:00:00Z",
      "shipDate_2":"2010-11-12T07:00:00Z",
      "shipDate_3":"2010-11-13T07:00:00Z",
      "shipMethod_1":"UPS Ground",
      "shipMethod_3":"UPS Ground3",
      "shipMethod_2":"UPS Ground2",
      "trackingNumber_3":"333",
      "trackingNumber_1":"2222",
      "trackingNumber_2":"221"
    }
  }
]
```

I need output like following

```
{  
  "trackingInfo":[  
    {  
      "shipDate":"2010-11-11T07:00:00Z",
      "shipMethod":"UPS Ground",
      "trackingNbr":"2222"
    },
    {  
      "shipDate":"2010-11-12T07:00:00Z",
      "shipMethod":"UPS Ground2",
      "trackingNbr":"221"
    },
    {  
      "shipDate":"2010-11-13T07:00:00Z",
      "shipMethod":"UPS Ground3",
      "trackingNbr":"333"
    }
  ]
}
```

the shipdate, shipmethod ,trackingnumber can be n numbers.
how to iterate using json key.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First `map` the array to iterate and then use `pluck` to get a list of keys.

Then as long as there is always the same amount of shipDate to shipMethod etc fields. filter the list of keys to only iterate the amount of times those field combinations exist.

Then construct the output of each object by dynamically looking up the key using 'shipDate__ concatenated with the index(incremented by 1 because your example starts at 1 and dw arrays start at 0):

```
%dw 2.0
output application/json

---

    payload map ((item, index) -> item.additionalData pluck($$) filter ($ contains 'shipDate')  map ((item2, index2) ->
        using(incIndex=(index2+1 as String)){ 
            "shipDate": item.additionalData[('shipDate_'++ incIndex)],
            "shipMethod": item.additionalData[('shipMethod_'++ incIndex)],
             "trackingNbr": item.additionalData[('trackingNumber_'++ incIndex)],
        }
    )

)
```

In DW 1.0 syntax:

```
%dw 1.0
%output application/json  
---
payload map ((item, index) -> item.additionalData pluck ($$) filter ($ contains 'shipDate') map ((item2, index2) -> 
    using (incIndex = (index2 + 1 as :string))
      {
        "shipDate": item.additionalData[('shipDate_' ++ incIndex)],
        "shipMethod": item.additionalData[('shipMethod_' ++ incIndex)],
        "trackingNbr": item.additionalData[('trackingNumber_' ++ incIndex)]
      }))
```

It's mostly the same, except:

- `output` => `%output`
- `String` => `:string`

Comment: how we can do this in dw 1.0.